# How can I find out the root element of all active windows on the os x

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, core-foundation, quartz

I have a some trouble.
Сan anyone tell briefly about the hierarchy of windows in os x . 
And if it  possible about ways to interact directly with the help of objective c and some frameworks.
P.S. I need to know characteristics of root element of all active windows.
On the next step i need to know all GUI controls of each active windows.

Answer (score 0):

I find some way to get it.
You can go to AppKit or Quartz.
Some specific info about windows and use Apple Accessibility API you can get by ApplicationServices.
Hope that this answer can help for you.